# Autowire a bean in a Main program

Tags: java, spring

I need to autowire a bean in a standalone main program as i need to set Up some data . Main program has a dependency on "MyDependencyClass" to set up some services.
I am unclear as to how to get the ApplicationContext as the "MyDependencyClass" is not declared in any spring xml,nor the class is annotated. Please help.

My main program :

```
public class Main {

  @Autowired 
   private MyDependencyClass myDepClass

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main main1 = new Main();
  main1.callDep();
}
  private void callDep(){
  myDepClass.setUp();
}
}
```

MyDependencyClass:

```
public class MyDependencyClass {
   public void setUp() {
    Sysout("Setting up");
}

}
```

Comment: Please read a tutorial on standalone Spring DI. It's really basic stuff.

Comment: @PauChorro - it still doesn't cover creating application context. It really is a question equivalent of "I haven't done any research, please rewrite a tutorial to suit my needs".

Comment: Hmm,since i am new to spring ,this is a doubt. I am not configuring xml's ,most of them get the application context through a config file,but i am using annotations.

Comment: I was able to proceed without component annotation.

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't define beans in .xml you need to use @Component or @Repository annotation based on your class type. [annotations](http://www.techferry.com/articles/spring-annotations.html)